# AES KeyManagerFactory not available

Tags: java, security, ssl, cryptography

I'm facing an exception telling me that "AES KeyManagerFactory not available".

Here is my code:

```
try {
    LOG.warn("Configuring SSL connection on port 8085");
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
    keystore.load(new FileInputStream("/.peg.jceks"),
            "password".toCharArray());

    KeyStore kstrust = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
    String truststorelocation = "/.peg.jceks";
    kstrust.load(new FileInputStream(truststorelocation), "changeit".toCharArray());

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(keystore, "password".toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory tmf =
            TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(kstrust);

    context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    SSLServerSocketFactory sf = context.getServerSocketFactory();
    SSLServerSocket ss = (SSLServerSocket)sf.createServerSocket(8085);
    ss.setNeedClientAuth(true);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    LOG.error("Problem configuring SSL", e.getMessage());
}
```

and I am facing this exception

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: AES KeyManagerFactory not available
     at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
     at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.java:10)
```

Could anyone mind to resolve this please?

Comment: I've made an educated guess where the exception occurred. But please always indicate the location of the exception in the code. We don't have the line numbers!

Comment: I've also edited the tags and the exception a bit. [tag:encryption] is often abused to mean [tag:cryptography]. TLS offers a lot more than just encryption. [tag:java-security] and just `security` is too generic; just using [tag:java] and [tag:cryptography] should suffice. Note that [tag:java-security] has 0 followers and only 28 questions; i.e. nobody is interested in the tag.

Comment: Also very important: I've seen questions by you that have clearly been answered. You don't seem to accept those questions so they don't stay open. Please select the answer that suits your need and [accept that one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), or indicate what's still missing from the answers of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/KeyManagerFactory.html#getDefaultAlgorithm()):

> The default algorithm can be changed at runtime by setting the value of the `"ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm"` security property (set in the Java security properties file or by calling `Security.setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String))` to the desired algorithm name.

So somebody - possibly you - set this value to a wrong one. The key manager should indicate the kind of authentication keys and certificates it handles. It should not indicate a symmetric cipher. Symmetric ciphers are not used during the authentication phase of TLS (probably unless PSK cipher suites is being used).

On my system the algorithm returns `SunX509` which is a much more sensible result, X509 being the certificates used to perform regular client/server authentication within TLS.

Comment: The previous error got resolved and this is the new one i am stuck with.. java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Given final block not properly padded

Comment: Can we use a single keystore file as both trust store and keystore??

Comment: That should be possible yes. Final block not properly padded usually means an incorrect key or password.

Comment: Hi Maarten, i used the following command to list out the keys..
keytool -list -keystore <keystorename> -storetype JCEKS -storepass <password>
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Given final block not properly padded 

If an incorrect key exists how to figure out that its the problem is with the stored keys..  I am sure about the Password.

This command is working fair. Its listing out all the keys.. but programatically it throwing this exception

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the key specific password is incorrect. But this is turning out to be a debugging question... that's kinda hard to do from here.

Comment: In the code i did not provide any key specific password.. and there are many keys and certs in the keystore.. as Java handle all this. Please correct me if i am wrong..